# How do you merge two conflicting files with Unison

Tags: synchronization, unison

I am having two nfs servers across which I am trying to sync files.
I have the unison profile sync.prf this way.

```
root = /home/ubuntu/nfs                                # shared directory on server1
root = ssh://ubuntu@XX.XX.XX.XX//home/ubuntu/nfs       # shared directory on server2
ignore = Name .git
merge = Name /home/ubuntu/nfs/*txt
```

There is a hello.txt file in server1 as well as in server2. I am trying to merge the content from files across the servers.

While I run the profile using `unison sync.prf`, I am getting the failed synchronization.
The error is as follows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-shivam:~$ unison sync.prf                              
Contacting server...
Connected [//sshtest-vm-intern//home/ubuntu/nfs -> //ubuntu-shivam//home/ubuntu/nfs]
Looking for changes
  Waiting for changes from server
Reconciling changes

local          sshtest-v...
changed  <=M=>            hello.txt  [f] m

Proceed with propagating updates? [] y
Propagating updates


UNISON 2.48.4 started propagating changes at 18:04:36.00 on 05 Jan 2023
100%  00:00 ETAFailed [hello.txt]: 'merge' preference not set for hello.txt
UNISON 2.48.4 finished propagating changes at 18:04:36.01 on 05 Jan 2023


Saving synchronizer state
Synchronization incomplete at 18:04:36  (0 items transferred, 0 skipped, 1 failed)
  failed: hello.txt
```

I have tried implementing the merge option in following some ways, but not getting the successful synchronization.

```
Path /home/ubuntu/nfs = update
*.txt update
*.txt = update
Name /home/ubuntu/nfs/*.txt
/home/ubuntu/nfs = update
Name /home/ubuntu/nfs/*.txt = merge=update
Path /home/ubuntu/nfs = merge=update
merge = diff3 -m /home/ubuntu/nfs/*.txt OLD /home/ubuntu/nfs/*txt > NEW
```

Kindly someone help me with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the `merge` option isn't correct. It should look something like

```
merge = Name *txt -> diff3 -m CURRENT1 CURRENTARCH CURRENT2 > NEW
```

See the see the [*Merging Conflicting Versions* section of the Unison Manual](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#merge) for details and examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike. Here, I am confused in replacing these variables namely CURRENT1 CURRENTARCH CURRENT2. Can you help me with these by going through the state of the servers I have given above(let say I want to merge hello.txt file).